# Error in large file uploading in spring boot gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

How to upload large files in spring boot gradle?

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
    final CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean multipartFilterRegistrationBean() {
    final MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(multipartFilter);
    filterRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("multipartResolverBeanName", "commonsMultipartResolver");
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

When I gave above code then upload only large files. Not upload byte and kb files.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multipart maxFileSize in your application.yml or properties easily.

```
  multipart:
     maxFileSize: 30MB
```

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 properties you can set:

> multipart.max-file-size=1Mb
>
> Max file size. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.
>
> multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
>
> Max request size. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.

You can find the list of all properties at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html